# How do i print only (bottem) part of a dictionary in python3?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, printing, element

I have created a dictionary by counting a list of positives words(positives.txt) over a list of tweets(tweets.txt).
Now im trying to print the top 5 used postitive words with respective scores. 
I have managed to sort the scores and able to print the whole list of words with their scores, like:

(rest of list...)
wordx 5
wordy 28
wordz 35

My goal is to print (just) a top 3:

wordz 35
wordy 28
wordx 5

I tried giving indexes en subscripts at different places but keep getting error messages like:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
print(word[3], score[3])

IndexError: string index out of range
    print(word[0:5], score[0:5])
  TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Current Code:

```
def positive_word(tweets, positives):
    """prints the top 5 most used positive words"""

    x = {}
    #for l in range(5):
    for l in range(len(positives)):
        x[positives[l]] = 0
    #for m in range (5):
    for m in range (len(tweets)):
        #for n in range (5):
        for n in range (len(positives)):
            if positives[n] in tweets[m]:
                x[positives[n]] += 1

    for word, score in sorted(x.items(), key = lambda key : key[1]):
        print(word, score)
```

Comment: "sorted" returns a list on which you can apply the subscription.

Comment: `sorted(x.items(), key = lambda key : key[1])[:5]` should solve your problem